# MysQL con sentencias preparadas desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo uso de sentencias preparadas desde mi PHP con la función **bind_param()**. Esto es lo que tengo en mi código **index.php**:

```
$select_comment = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments where student_id=?");
$select_comment->bind_param("i", $user_id);
$select_comment->execute();

$select_answers = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM answers where student_id=? and exercise_time=?");
$select_answers->bind_param("is", $user_id, $ex_tim);
$select_answers->execute();

$insert_comment = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (student_id, comment, time) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$insert_comment->bind_param("iss", $user_id,$comment,$ex_tim);
$insert_comment->execute();
```

Sin embargo, me está dando unos problemas que no se solucionar.

Alguien sabe por qué me sale este error en la línea `$select_answers->bind_param("is", $user_id, $ex_tim);`?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

El metodo `prepare` devuelve `FALSE` si no fue posible preparar la sentencia. Por ello en la línea siguiente te da ese error. Revisa la query porque da error.

[Fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: La query funciona si la hago sin prerare así: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM answers where student_id=$user_id and exercise_time='".$ex_tim."'";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql);` Pero con prepare no se porqué no funciona

Comment: Usa `errorInfo`para ver que error da el prepare. https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php